# Update FirebaseUI FirebaseRecyclerView Child on user click

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I am starting with the Firebase Database. I have made a small Task Tracker application in which I am able to push items to DB. I am using Firebase UI and FriebaseRecyclerView.

The issue is I am unable to update childs on item clicks, from the firebaseRecyclerView. Below is the code for my view holder. But on checkbox clicks my DB is not updated as expected.

```
 public static class TaskViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
 TextView title,description;
 CheckBox checkBox;
 FirebaseAuth mAuth;
 FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
    public TaskViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
        description= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.Description);
        checkBox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkboxTaskRow);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        firebaseUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.taskList);
                final FirebaseRecyclerAdapter firebaseRecyclerAdapter = (FirebaseRecyclerAdapter) recyclerView.getAdapter();
                if(checkBox.isChecked()) {
                    SpannableString content = new SpannableString(title.getText());
                    content.setSpan(new StrikethroughSpan(), 0, content.length(), 0);
                    title.setText(content);
                    content = new SpannableString(description.getText());
                    content.setSpan(new StrikethroughSpan(), 0, content.length(), 0);
                    description.setText(content);
                }
                else
                {
                    description.setText(description.getText().toString());
                    title.setText(title.getText().toString());
                }
            }
        });

    } }
```

Also Below is my adapter code

```
  final FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<UnitTask,TaskViewHolder> adapter =
            new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<UnitTask, TaskViewHolder>(UnitTask.class,R.layout.task,TaskViewHolder.class,userRef) {
                @Override
                protected void populateViewHolder(TaskViewHolder viewHolder, UnitTask model, int position) {
                    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
                    firebaseUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                    viewHolder.title.setText(model.getTitle());
                    viewHolder.description.setText(model.getDescription());
                    viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(model.isCompleted());
                }


            };
```

My UnitTask class

```
public class UnitTask {

public String title;
public String description;
boolean completed;

public UnitTask(String title, String description, boolean completed) {
    this.title = title;
    this.description = description;
    this.completed = completed;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public boolean isCompleted() {
    return completed;
}

public void setCompleted(boolean completed) {
    this.completed = completed;
}

public UnitTask() {
    // Do Nothing
}

}
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Also I am just starting with android so do expect of me to make silly mistakes.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A work around to get your purpose is:

1) when user check on an item, let push a "special value" to firebase db.

2) In FirebaseRecyclerAdapter#populateViewHolder:if item has "special value", change the layout

**UPDATE**

Try the example from google:

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/database

Let see the implementation of Star button.

in PostListFragment.java you will find:

```
// Determine if the current user has liked this post and set UI accordingly
if (model.stars.containsKey(getUid())) {
    viewHolder.starView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_toggle_star_24);
} else {
    viewHolder.starView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_toggle_star_outline_24);
}

// Bind Post to ViewHolder, setting OnClickListener for the star button
viewHolder.bindToPost(model, new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View starView) {
        // Need to write to both places the post is stored
        DatabaseReference globalPostRef = mDatabase.child("posts").child(postRef.getKey());
        DatabaseReference userPostRef = mDatabase.child("user-posts").child(model.uid).child(postRef.getKey());

        // Run two transactions
        onStarClicked(globalPostRef);
        onStarClicked(userPostRef);
    }
});
```

Comment: Well I think that wont be a generic solution. There should be a built in solution for this right?

Comment: yes. Google has already built an example. Wait a minute, I'll provide it on my update answer.

Comment: Thanks! That really helped.

Answer (score 0):

@Muhammad Hassan Niazi update your database record inside that if condition either using push or setvalue method

Comment: But how do I get the key for the child ?